# Tomcat9 remote debugging

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat9

Is there some trick for remote debugging a Tomcat9 from outside localhost?

I have a AWS bastion -> server setup and on the server itself

`ss -tunlp` sees  `127.0.0.1:8787 0.0.0.0:*`

but nmap on the bastion server doesn't see 8787 open

the other (visible) stuff on the server ss lists as *:port which looks "wider" for sure

The security group for the server is OK and a reachability analysis confirms it. A also see all the other stuff (MySQL, RDP, SSH etc) that I use in exactly the same way

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/tomcat9 (on Ubuntu 20) has the line

`#JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`

which should be uncommented but apparently is implicitly for binding the listener only on localhost. Changing the port format to

`JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:8080,server=y,suspend=n"`

widens the binding to external access

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).